# How can I run a custom version of dpl on Travis CI?

Tags: rubygems, travis-ci

Travis-CI uses the [dpl deploy tool](https://github.com/travis-ci/dpl) to deploy your application.

I've made a [fork of the repo](https://github.com/jasny/dpl) which includes a number of improvements concerning deploying to AWS. In the before deploy step, I clone the repo and build them gem.

I've found that using `edge: local` under the `deploy` section in `.travis.yml`, will cause Travis to add `--local` to `gem install dpl` command.

Travis should scan the current working directory for this gem, but that isn't working correctly. The `gem` command is unable to find the new gem.

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'dpl' (>= 0) in any repository

The command "rvm 1.9.3 --fuzzy do ruby -S gem install dpl --pre --local" failed and exited with 2 during .
```

I tried copying it to the current working dir (same as `$TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR`), as well as to `$HOME`, neither works.

This is the depoy part of my `.travis.yml`.

```
before_deploy:
- export ELASTIC_BEANSTALK_LABEL=$(git tag --contains)
- git clone -b master https://github.com/jasny/dpl.git /tmp/dpl
- (cd /tmp/dpl && gem build dpl.gemspec && cp *.gem "$TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR")
deploy:
  provider: elasticbeanstalk
  edge: local
  access_key_id: ...
  secret_access_key:
    secure: ...
  region: eu-west-1
  app: dms
  env: dms-travis-test
  bucket_name: elasticbeanstalk-eu-west-1-930677074220
  bucket_path: dms
  on:
    branch: travis-deploy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `edge: local` is currently broken in the Travis build environment, caused by ruby gems version 2.4.5.

Ruby gems v1.x the `--local` flag would scan the current working directory for gems of any version. However ruby gems v2.x no longer does this and requires you to use the file name of the gem.

The [travis-build](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-build) application was never modified to cope with this change.

As a workaround you can downgrade to ruby gems v1.8.30.

```
before_install:
- gem update --system 1.8.30
```

Comment: I've created a pull request to fix this issue: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-build/pull/466

Comment: I still have error after adding `gem update --system 1.8.30` in `before_install`. I've exactly the same error. Could you help? Does it still necessary to copy the gem to $HOME?

Comment: Nevermind. Apparently I need to copy the gem file to travis build folder.